# Test if error validation text match a string using if statement doesn't works

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a validation in my User model which check an input text if it have a value or not :

```
validate :picture_name
...
...
...

def picture_name
    errors[:picture].push "no_name" if namePicture.blank?
end
```

html text field:

```
<input type="text" name="namePicture" />
```

in my view i want to check if that @user.errors[:picture] contains only **1 error** and the error text is **"no_name"** (no_name is the error added by picture_name validation) :

```
<% if @user.errors.count.eql? 1 && @user.errors['picture'] == "no_name" %>
   <h1> test works </h1>
<% else %>
   <h1> test doesn't works </h1>
<% end %>
```

but i don't know why it always shows me "test doesn't works" even when errors['picture'] contains just (one) "no_name" as error !

there is some error in my if statement ? or what ?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the solution if it interest someone, in my above statement :

```
if @user.errors.count.eql? 1 && @user.errors['picture'] == "no_name"
```

i use **&&** operator which is high precedence, this means that my statement look like this :

```
if @user.errors.count.eql? ( 1 && @user.errors['picture'] == "no_name" )
```

or more explicitly

```
if @user.errors.count.eql? true
```

which is incorrect

so, the solution is :

**using parentheses :**

```
if (@user.errors.count.eql? 1) && (@user.errors['picture'] == "no_name")
```

**or using "AND" operator which is lower precedence:**

```
if @user.errors.count.eql? 1 and @user.errors['picture'] == "no_name"
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it has to do with setting errors with a symbol (:picture), but testing on a string ('picture') + errors[:picture] contains an array, not a string

Comment: doesn't work even with symbol :picture, when i show the error with : error['picture'] it works but when i check it inside if statement it doesn't works